# Vscode host verification key failed. Zscaler

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, zscaler

Been searching several times to find the answer to this issue. Hope someone else has similar settings.

0. I am using MacOS Big Sur. Vscode 1.61.2
1. I am working remotely from office and laptop has zscaler installed.
2. In Vscode terminal all git push/pull etc works fine with my id_rsa.
3. Using inbuilt Vscode menu / icons doing the same thing all fail with host key verification failed.
4. When using terminal inside or outside vscode, there is always a "warning: the RSA host key for <GitHub internal site> differs from the key for the IP address xxx.xx.xx.xx'
   Are you sure you want to continue?I have to enter yes, then git operation executes OK.

I believe above is due to zscaler app.

Q. Is the above prompt causing in-built vscode git calls to fail?
Any way around it?

I'm pretty sure this basic inbuilt SCM works for everyone with remote repos.

Comment: It's not zscaler, it's the fact that the RSA host key for your site changed. You may have multiple servers implementing the internal site; if so, you should make sure they all provide the *same* host key to clients, so that the clients can see that they're all providing the same data. (This is generally an ssh issue, since SSL site checking uses a different method.)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the reason. It works EVERY SINGLE TIME from a terminal but NEVER from vscode built in options.

Comment: It's still the issue. Clear out the old, incorrect key from the known_hosts file, and put the correct key in, so that you don't get the complaint. Presumably vscode is just disabling the interactive "should I continue" option, so that the answer is always "no, don't continue". See [this ServerFault Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/321167/549786).

Comment: Hi @torek...I do apologise, I misread RSA key when you said RSA host key. Your solution is working. I'll know what to do if this happens again!

Comment: In this scenario, the old RSA host key likely isn't actually incorrect. It's simply that the old RSA host key is the actual one from GitHub while @DodgyD is no longer connecting to GitHub directly, but to zScaler - which then acts as a man-in-the-middle between them and GitHub.
Removing the actual GutHub RSA host key from `known_hosts` may work in practice in this scenario, but it's dubious from a security perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a zscaler making VPN less secure one solution at a time.  Seeing you are not logging directly into your final host - it seems the RSA key is whatever host is playing as intermediary for the connection.